# Is using an free and anonymous VPN service safe?

Tags: privacy, vpn

There are VPN services that are totally free and high speed vpn which makes me think, how can they offer such a service for free without ads nor donations?

Is using this VPN safe?
Regarding my accounts emails/FACEBOOK and  regarding my laptop and IPAD info?

Comment: I would say that you need to consider using a reputable company for your VPN Solution.  You will often find that although these are 'free' they will often limit your bandwidth use, and may well sell your information to 3rd parties.

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to be 100% certain, but bear in mind that it's entirely possible for your VPN provider to see ALL of your traffic. Personally I do not sign into any personal account when using a VPN, particularly a free one.

I'm guessing that you want something to bypass country specific law? The safest way is to purchase your own VPS (which you can find for a few dollars a month) and route your traffic through that, then you are in charge of your data.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that when you use a VPN service, that service will be able to collect all the information which could usually be collected by your internet service provider. That means using a VPN service for privacy is only reasonable when you trust the VPN provider more than you trust your ISP.

I usually would recommend you to look into the privacy policy of your VPN service to learn if and under what conditions they share private information with 3rd parties. But it looks like the service you linked to doesn't even have one, which should be a huge red flag.